# Pointer Ownership

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an array of pointers: `pArray[rows][columns]`, where each element can contain a pointer to an object. Some of the objects were instantiated in `main()` on the heap, and some were instantiated by objects themselves also on the heap: That is, I passed `pArray` to an object member function, and that function created a new object, and put a pointer to it in `pArray`.

Now when I want to delete pointers to objects from `pArray`, is there ownership in play here? Meaning, if an object created a new object and placed a pointer to it in `pArray`, can only the creator object call delete on that pointer? Or can I do it from `main()`, and other objects by passing the array to them?

Some more details:

The code simulates a predator prey model on a grid (`pArray`). So I begin by reading in the initial grid config from a file, and instantiate objects (predators, and prey), on `pArray` from `main()`. But predators and prey can breed, so objects spawn new objects and by passing `pArray` to them, they instantiate their children on `pArray`.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question generically.  It's up to you to figure out ownership issues, based on the intent of your code.  But you're free to invoke `delete` anywhere, so long as do it exactly once for each object, and never try to use an object once it's been deleted.  Smart pointers can typically be used to reduce the burden of tracking ownership.

Comment: Does it make sense for these objects to have a single "owner"?  If not, you should look at `shared_ptr`.

Comment: It almost sounds like you're asking a reference counting question, which is handled in COM (if you're on Windows). I don't know about non-Windows platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no "ownership" on pointers in C++, if the pointer is valid (contains  proper reference to data / object), you can deallocate it anywhere issuing `delete` command.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think stating that there is no ownership is overstating it.  Ownership is a general concept that the programmer should be aware of, it is just not enforced by the language.

Answer (score 5):

With raw pointers ownership is purely a concept. As long as you are working with raw pointers, it is entirely up to you to assign ownership of pointed object to anyone and anything. It is a matter of your design. There's no such "rule" that the object should be deleted by whoever created them. Ownership can be retained or passed on. Ownership can be shared (as in reference-counted ownership schemes). Again, it is a matter of your design and your intent.

Various smart pointer classes will help you to express your intent and implement your intent. With raw pointers you have to remember who owns what and do everything manually.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor of objects is subject to the same public/protected/private like every other method. So, if the destructor is public, anyone can call delete on the object.

The only important thing is that it happens exactly once, and only after nobody is using the object anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ownership concept for pointers in C++ .As far as I understood your question, Yes you can delete that object from main() in case of dynamic memory allocation. The memory allocated to that object would only be freed only when the program ends or the Object array goes out of scope and the destructor for the class is called.